# Restrain variable to a bounded region (interval) formulation in Mixed Integer Linear Programming

Tags: optimization, linear-programming, mixed-integer-programming

I have 4 non negative real variable that are A, B, C and X. Based on the current problem that I have, I notice that the variable X must belong to the interval of [B,C] and the relation will be a bunch of if-else conditions like this:

```
If A < B:
  x = B
elseif A > C:
  x = C
elseif B<=A<=C:
  x = A
```

As you can see, it quite difficult to reformulate as a Mixed Integer Programming problem with corresponding decision variable (d1, d2 and d3). I have try reading some instructions regarding if-then formulation using big M method at this site:
 https://www.math.cuhk.edu.hk/course_builder/1415/math3220/L2%20(without%20solution).pdf but it seem that this problem is more challenging than their tutorial.
Could you kindly provide me with a formulation for this situation ?
Thank you very much !

Comment: Maybe I misunderstand the questions, but why not just adding the constraints B <= x and x <= C?

Comment: If you would turn your comment into an answer, I would upvote it!

Comment: Michiel uit het Broek: Sorry but could explain the reason behind this for me  ?